# Org mode - text problem in SVG images

Tags: tikz-pgf, emacs, org-mode

I have a problem when exporting latex tikz code as svg image in org mode.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{svg}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

#+HEADER: :exports results
#+HEADER: :imagemagick yes
#+HEADER: :results output graphics file
#+HEADER: :file contour.svg :imoutoptions -flatten -fill black
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (-2,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=-180,end angle=0] (-1,0) -- (1,0) arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=180,end angle=0] (2,0) -- (3,0);
   \draw[black,thin, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray] (0,0) ellipse (1.7cm and 1.1cm);
   \draw[-latex, thick] (0.5,0.4).. controls (1,1)  .. (0.8,1.5);
   \draw[-latex, thick] (-0.5,1.5).. controls (-1,1)  .. (-0.8,0.5);
   \node[text=blue] at (0,0.2) {System};
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_src
```

Any text present in the image when I try to run the code above in org mode:

[image]

But, the text is visible when I open the image file with Inkscape:

[image]

What can I do to obtain text in the svg image in the html file ?